# Get Logs on User Password Reset Button

Tags: debug-logs, reset-password

Greetings Salesforce Friends!

I've got a bit of a weird situation around Users in a Community getting the wrong email when we use the User Record Reset Button.

Is there a way to get the logs for this button. I have put a Tracer on the community user, and on myself, but I can't find the process that is executing the email.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

the email template sent to the community user is defined in the Setup > Digital Experiences > All Sites > near the community use, click on Workspaces > Administration > Emails [image]

Comment: This is not the issue. The issue is that I have 2 communities. We changed the permission for the first community and gave a permission set for the second. However, the user is still receiving FOrgot password emails for the first community.

Comment: Hi, apparently, the email template used is the oldest community "Activated" assigned to the profile, if you deactivate the first community the email template of the second community will be used.

Consider if this reset password can be more specific like a custom button that does the reset password by Apex and find the correct email template by custom settings or other parameters.

Apex to reset manually with a specific template email

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_system_resetPasswordWithEmailTemplate

Comment: Thanks Willian, I discovered this as well. When there is profile in play and shared across two communities it looks at the oldest community to send the email.

Answer (score 0):

There is buried in the documentation a statement about the oldest community taking priority

> If the user is a member of multiple active sites, the email comes from the oldest active site.
> https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_customize_email.htm&type=5

However, I still don't know how to access the logs to verify that this is what's happening from a debug log. Testing does indicate that this is the case, but would like to get access to the technical side of things.